# Conjugacy class of permutatuion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have permutation $\partial$ = (1 10)(2 6 3 7 6 8 12)(4)(9 11) $\in S_{12}$ and i need to find number of elements in conjugacy class of permutation $\partial$ in group of all permutations. 
I dont understand how to solve this problem. How can i find conjugacy class if disjoint cycles have different length?

Comment: See inf you can answer the following questions: (1) Do you know conjugation is an action of any group on itself? It could also help, perhaps, to know that it is an action by automorphisms, (2) Do you know how orbit of an element is related to the index of some subgroup? (3) Do you what elements **exactly** are conjugated with $\;\partial\;$ (weird greek letter you chose here...) ?

Answer (score 1):

The conjugacy class of a permutation consists of all the permutations with the same cycle structure. How many of those are there in $S_{12}$ with structure $(xx)(xxxxxxx)(x)(xx)$?

Remember that disjoint cycles commute, so the order of the cycles doesn't matter, nor does the order of elements in each cycle.

Comment: so only 4 elements in conjugacy class?

Comment: No. Read more carefully. You need to count the number of permutations with that cycle structure. There are lots. Here's one: $(12)(3456789)(10)(11,12)$. I suggest you write out all the conjugacy classes for $S_4$ first, to get an idea of what they look like.

Comment: So there is some sort of formula?

Comment: Yes there is "some sort of formula" that depends on knowing how to count patterns of subsets of a set. That's material standard in a discrete mathematics course and more than can be taught in an answer to this question here. Someone might post an answer to your particular question, but you might not learn much from it.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{12!}{(2^2*2!)(7^1*1!)(3^1*1!)(1^1*1!)}$

Comment: i found formula for this and i got : $\frac{12!}{4*2*7}$

Comment: ok, I though my reasoning is correct. like our solution differ by multiple of 6

Comment: Not quite. The two two-cycles could have been constructed in two orders. Check your computation for $(**)(**)$ in $S_4$.

Comment: @EthanBolker $\frac{12!}{4!*2*7}$ is incorrect?

Comment: The answer is here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_formula_in_symmetric_group